# How to recognize that character is at end of maze?

Tags: calculator, maze, ti-basic

I have two separate levels for my maze game for the ti-84 calculator, which both have identical code. Although, one of the levels does not complete when the character reaches the end, and treats the final spot as a wall.

```
ClrHome
1→A
1→B
For(y,1,8
For(x,1,16
Output(y,x,sub(" XD", 1+[F](y,x),1
End:End
Repeat K=21 or [F](A,B)=2
getkey→K
If Ans
Output(A,B," ")
sum(△List(Ans={25,34}))
A+Ans([F](A+Ans,B)≠1)→A
sum(△List(K={24,26}))
B+Ansnot([F](A,B+Ans)→B
Output(A,Ans,"Θ")
End
ClrHome
Display "You Win"
Pause
Goto 99
```

Comment: If only one of your levels doesn't work and both levels use the same code the error is most likely in the matrix that backs your maze. You treat `1` as a wall and `2` as the goal. The fix is probably making the goal square of both matrices `2`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your logic for horizontal movement, and I would be willing to bet that in the maze that works, you move either up or down onto the goal, while in the maze that doesn't work, you move right or left onto the goal.

Your vertical movement coefficient of Ans, `([F](A+Ans,B)≠1)`, evaluates to true whenever the current cell is not 1, a wall. On the other hand, your horizontal movement coefficient of Ans, `not([F](A,B+Ans)`, evaluates to true whenever the current cell is not 1 or 2, a wall *or the goal*. Change it to be similar to the vertical logic, `([F](A,B+Ans)≠1)`,and your game should be fixed.

Edit:

Also, for the sake of performance, I would recommend enclosing most of the logic in an if then statement, because it doesn't need to run if a key is not pressed.

```
If K
Then
[Game Logic]
End
```